# Scala and exception handling

Tags: scala, exception-handling

I am curious why exception handling is a topic often ignored in Scala. Is it the goal of the language (or the style) to not rely on exception handling except for external input/code?

I was hoping the style guide had some discussion on exception checking/handling. Is there a good reference that I could consult to understand if there are any differences in handling exceptions in Scala vs. languages I'm more used to (C++/C#/Java/Ruby/etc)?

Would someone with some Scala years under their belt be willing to write down guidelines for exception handling that are Scala specific? or is the answer simply "do as you would in Java"? What is "the functional way"?

Comment: [This article](http://tersesystems.com/2012/12/27/error-handling-in-scala/) provides a pretty good primer.  Can you read it, and then edit your question to identify what you don't specifically understand?

Comment: The Functional way is to use `Either`.  It returns either an instance of Left[L] or an instance of Right[R]. By convention, Left is used to represent failure and Right is used to represent success.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It's probably worth noting that Scala now provides a `Try` trait, which serves a similar purpose to Either, but also passes the exception information along in the case of a Failure. `Try { "foo".toInt }` returns `Failure(java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "foo")`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Good functional style does not need defensive coding nearly as much as the imperative style.  **try** and **catch** is not the only control structure which is neglected in Scala (and other functional languages); **for** and **while** loops are endangered species and even **if...else** is used more selectively (although much more effectively, since it returns a value).

In the functional world, you match your code to the shape of the data.  Or you choose a shape which gives your code the structure you want.  This is true not only with **Option** and **Either** but **List** and **Set** and **Map** and more.  All of them are paired with powerful Higher Order Functions - **map**, **fold**, **filter** etc.

To take a trivial example, if a Java or C++ coder wants to fetch the first (or all) of the items in a list and manipulate it, they either have to first check that the list is not empty or wrap it in  **try/catch** to handle the error.  If they have to deal with a collection of lists, the latter option is more likely to be chosen (and even less likely to match the context which might generate an error).

In Scala you can simply do this to the list of Ints called **xs**:

```
  xs.headOption map (_ * 2)
  // Returns twice the first item - if there is one - as an Option
```

or

```
  xs map (_ * 2)
  // Doubles everything in the list.  Returns a list.
```

If there is nothing in the list, nothing will happen.  If you want something to happen, you can detect the failure and react.

```
  xs.headOption map (_ * 2) orElse Some(0)
  // Returns Some(twice the head item) if there is one or Some(0)
  xs.headOption map (_ * 2) getOrElse 0
  // Returns twice the head item or 0 if there is none
```

Even better, if you are dealing with a lists of lists, any one of which might be empty, mapping over each of them will produced results for every populated list and no problem at all with any empty ones.  That is very powerful when dealing with large collections of unpredictable data.

What these functional types (Option and Either and List and Map and all the other - sorry to use the ugly word - monads) also offer, *very* importantly, is separation of concerns.  Notice how I used **map** in all the above examples.  In two examples it is **Option.map**, while in the other it is **List.map**.  In all cases, **map** is doing the same thing: ¨Apply my function to the data inside that container, preserving the context¨.  If it is a list context, you get a list of transformed data back.  If it is a ¨may or may not exist¨ context, you may get your transformed object.  If it is a ¨this could really go badly wrong¨ context, you either get your object or a chance to complain.  And so on.

So you get a separation of concerns between the action you want to perform and the context in which it is applied.  The big advantage is that if you decide to change the context (e.g. **Set** of unique objects rather than arbitrary **List** of objects), the rest of the code doesn´t need to change at all.  **map** will still do the right thing (as will **filter**, **fold** and the rest).

Built-in imperative keywords like **try..catch** or **if...else...if...else** do not have that power.  For a start, they have no real meaning of their own and have to be bodged together (distorting the code tangled within them) and they offer no guarantee.  Imagine having used those to manage an arbitrary list of objects and then deciding you want to guarantee *uniqueness*.  How much of that imperative code will you have to change?  How can you be confident it will work?

Leave exceptions to deal with the truly unexpected and unsolveable.  Functional types can be confident about their guarantees, to help you avoid the common and predictable errors.

Comment: I would add that exceptions should be used, as the word says, to handle exceptional situations, i.e. errors, not to build the normal flow of control. That's why a function that might not return any result should have a result type `Option` instead of modeling the no-result-found situation by throwing an exception.

Comment: Nice answer (+1), especially for explaining that monadic types like `Option` are a good substitute for options. I often see exception as a jump into the void, in the hope you land somewhere. Options are rather taking an escape door into a tunnel that guides you out to a safe place. You might want to mention continuations (also supported by Scala) as yet another way of dealing with failure, see e.g. Chapter 29 of http://cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/smlbook/book.pdf.

Comment: I do like Bob Harper, but it is amusing to see him quoted here, given that he thinks Monads are overrated, hates type classes and thinks very little of Scala - not least because it has both of those *and* not the best implementation of either ;)

Comment: You probably know Robert Harper better than I do. I only read the book I cited and I find it a very good reading. Of course he has his own views, which I cannot judge, since I am not an expert in FP, even though I like the subject a lot.

Comment: Although I like the Option/Either/etc, part of my has shivers when it comes to thinking about boxing/unboxing. I guess I will need to get over that. Is the use of twitter Try (scala.util.Try) also proper FP?

Comment: @WillIAm Sort of. **scala.util.Try** is much more functional than plain exceptions. It is compositional, *usually* preserves referential integrity, allows the creation of functions which can recover from a particular type of error in any code.  There are subtle dangers presented by its design, which are probably unresolvable in a language which tries to interoperate with Java.  Read the comments at the bottom of this: http://aboutwhichmorelater.tumblr.com/post/30409572482/scala-util-try

Answer (score 5):

Scala encourages the use of constructs like options and futures for error handling. First of all, lazy evaluation makes exceptions problematic, because there is a different stack when a function is executed than when it's queued to execute. Scala isn't lazy by default, but it can be lazy when you choose.

Also, options and futures are much more powerful than exceptions. You can chain operations on them, and they aren't limited to propagating straight up the stack like exceptions are. You can store them in collections and reduce duplication in handler code.

Pretty much the only time you use exceptions in Scala is for errors you can't handle that will kill your program anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call Option more powerful than exceptions. A chain of operations that may each fail with Option needs to test every result to see if they succeeded. An exception only incurs a cost if it's thrown. Options also change the types of every intermediate expression even for the cases where it can be proven that the input will never cause a failure. In my opinion they have different uses rather than one being more powerful.

Comment: If the chain is built using map, flatmap or one of the other HoFs, testing every step is not necessary, @Doval.  But you know that so I suppose you mean the testing inside map and flatmap.

Comment: @itsbruce Correct, that's what I mean. There's a pretty in-depth analysis of the performance trade-off [here](http://shipilev.net/blog/2014/exceptional-performance/). Since the trade-off depends on the frequency of the error case (which usually depends on what the caller does), and since both error-handling strategies change the type signatures of the functions, I think the most practical API design is to provide both and let the caller choose. That said, Karl is right that if lazy evaluation gets involved, it's easy to screw up unchecked exception handling.

Comment: As I am about to say in an answer of my own, the real power of these monads is that they let you choose a structure that matches the way you want your code to perform, without having to build something out of built-in keywords.

Comment: I disagree that options are used for error handling: When I look for a number with a certain property and I find no number, it does not mean I have an error. My computation simply terminates and gives a correct answer: `None`. On the contrary, I would say that languages that do not have an option type encourage the use of exception to model an optional result, which is conceptually wrong. Exceptions are for errors, not for expected results.

Comment: @Giorgio An exception doesn't necessarily mean something's gone conceptually wrong either. For example, if you're trying to recursively enumerate all solutions to a problem (or find the best one), you can use an exception to abort a line of search that led to a dead end. Think e.g. solving the [Eight queens puzzle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle). The definition of "error" is also pretty subjective. Some people argue that the job of e.g. `openFile` is to open a file, and if it can't then that's an error; I could argue there's no guarantee the file exists so it's not an error.

Comment: @Doval: Sure, what you consider an error and what you consider a normal negative result depends on the context, but this does not mean you shouldn't make this distinction and use different constructs. BTW, IMO a very interesting reading can be found in Chapter 29 of http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/smlbook/book.pdf

Comment: Citing from that book: "In
general, if efficiency is paramount, we tend to prefer exceptions if failure
is a rarity, and to prefer options if failure is relatively common. If, on
the other hand, static checking is paramount, then it is advantageous to
use options since the type checker will enforce the requirement that the
programmer check for failure, rather than having the error arise only at
run-time."

Comment: @Giorgio That chapter is actually what I was thinking of when I mentioned the Eight queens puzzle. On that note, static safety isn't an issue in Java since it has checked exceptions as well as the usual unchecked exceptions (although it's still an issue in most other languages.)

Comment: @Doval: ;-) I somehow remembered you were an SML fan. True, Java's checked exceptions are a nice alternative. But again, once you decide that something is an error, I think you should model it with an exception. If it is a 0-1 result, I think it should be an option.

Comment: Of course, Bob Harper have very particular views about how exceptions should be implemented :) https://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2012/08/14/haskell-is-exceptionally-unsafe/